# Does hapi-swagger ui provide onChange event validation for enum?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, hapi-swagger

I have an API `/v1/test/{note?}` I have added below code for this.

```
module.exports = [
       {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v1/test/{note?}',            
        config: {
            description: 'Greet user',
            notes: ['Use to greet a user'],
            tags: ['api'],
            handler: defaultHandler,
            timeout:{
                server:3000
            },
            validate: {
                params: {
                    note: Joi.string()
                        .required()
                        .valid(['param1', 'param2', 'param3'])
                        .description('Notes')

                    a: Joi.string().required().description('for param2')

                    b: Joi.string().required().description('for param3')
                },
                headers: {
                    name: Joi.string().required()
                },options: {
                    allowUnknown: true
                }
            }                               
        }
    }
];
```

In Swagger UI, is there any way if I select param2 from drop down then ui should display **a**, if I select param3 ui should display **b** or for param1 should display **name (header parameter)**

Answer (score 0):

You can define condition using Joi validation
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#anywhencondition-options

```
{
  note: Joi.string()
     .required()
     .valid(['param1', 'param2', 'param3'])
     .description('Notes'),
  a: Joi.string()
     .description('for param2')
     .when('note', { is: 'param2', then: Joi.required() }),
  b: Joi.string()
     .description('for param3')
     .when('note', { is: 'param3', then: Joi.required() }),
}
```

But **hapi-swagger didn't fully support that**. `when` is actually `alternatives` under the hood.

There is a list of features that can't be ported to swagger
https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/blob/master/usageguide.md#features-from-hapi-that-cannot-be-ported-to-swagger

Comment: thanks for your reply but with this, if I select param2 then UI will not hide (display:none) b parameter or if I select param3 then UI will not hide a parameter.

Comment: @ppb As I told you this is not supported by swagger yet